# Thymeleaf - Unquoting a part of inline JavaScript expression

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot project, and I need to render a part of a script element like the following. (Assume that `getMessage` function is defined somewhere else.)

Expected output:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var message = 'Hello, John' + getMessage();
    alert(message);
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

where `John` is a Spring model attribute.

Is it possible to make the whole `'Hello, John' + getMessage()` in a single Thymeleaf expression? Or, is assigning `Hello, John` and `getMessage()` to separate JavaScript variables then concatenating them the only way? I tried something like the following but it seems inlined JavaScript expression always gets quoted.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var message = /*[[|'Hello, ${name}' + getMessage()|]]*/ 'Hello, John';
    alert(message);
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Actual output:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var message = "'Hello, John' + getMessage()";
    alert(message);
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

By the way, I'm using Thymeleaf 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[...]]` notation is used for escaped inlining: it converts everything inside into a well-formed Javascript string.

Since you also want to call something, you need un-inlined version, using `[(...)]` notation:

```js
var message = /*[('Hello, ${name}' + getMessage())]*/ 'Hello, John';
```

Do note, however, that this way you won't get automatically escaped string, so if `${name}` contains single quote char (`'`), you will get malformed javascript expression. You will need to deal with this somehow.

More info: [Thymeleaf: Javascript Inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining)

Comment: Thanks. `/*[(|'Hello, ${name}' + getMessage()|)]*/` (with pipes) seems to be the way to go. Although, I should have clarified I'm using Spring Boot 1.5 which depends on Thymeleaf 2.1, and Thymeleaf 2.1 doesn't seem to understand `[(...)]` notation.

Comment: The `[(...)]` notation seems to be the new feature of Thmeleaf 3. https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/394

Comment: @DeokkeeMin, pipe is the [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions), so I think you would replace `'` chars with it, not just surround the thing. Come to think of it, try that without `[()]` notation.

Comment: Using pipes without `[[...]]` or `[(...)]` (i.e., `/*|...|*/`) didn't work. Apparently Thymeleaf doesn't pick it up as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Found that by using the special comment syntax `/*[+...+]*/` I could unquote the part following the thymeleaf expression.

```
/*[+
var message = [[|Hello, ${name}|]] + getMessage();
+]*/
```

Result:

```
var message = 'Hello, John' + getMessage();
```

Works on Thymeleaf 2.1.